Does the IRS check for errors and refund people who overpaid?
After paying state and federal taxes through one of the IRS' approved on-line tools, I received a letter from my state's IRS I've overpaid my taxes, basically gave me money back in the amount I overpaid. I don't know what error I made, but they've done this twice in the past two tax seasons. Does the federal IRS do this as well?

Didn't they tell you which lines they adjusted?

No, its a mystery to me what I did wrong.

Yes the IRS and the state tax authorities do check your work. They look for math mistakes, and items that should have been included that they have in their records. They will correct these problems.
Of course when they find an error it could save you money or cost you money.
They also don't know everything related yo your finances. If you donated a bunch of stuff to a charity and forget to claim it, they won't know to correct it.

Although when I've messed up, the letter usually has some indication of what I missed and the line number...
